# How to implement drag and drop between two tables, with all content.

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to do like this example in JS, Jquery or another compatible thing with MVC ?
http://www.satyam.com.ar/yui/invoice.html

I have a table with id and name for an order. I want to drag the row and drop it on another table. 
On drop, I want to show even all other columns on this id, not only id and name.

//I posted before but I don't think I was clear, so I posted a new example.

**Pseudo code:**

```
    {
     #dragableTableRow.drag;
    }

   { foreach ( cell in table where id= dragableTableRow.id )
         {
            DropDown it on #DropAbleTable ;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try jQuery **[sortable()](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)** or combination of jQuery **[draggable()](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)** and **[droppable()](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)**

You'll have to do the dragging on client-side so no issues on MVC.